# fragment caching and expiring amazon s3 links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, authentication, amazon-s3

On the app I am working on I just implemented fragment caching for a threaded activity flow. Each thread is cached  I gained almost 50% in processing time and it works fine, but a side effect I didn't anticipate is that amazon s3 links to attachments expire.

How can I have the links regenerated on each page refresh and at the same time avoid having to reload the whole conversation? In other words, is there some sort of `after_filter :regenerate_uploads` I can do through rails or javascript.

I'm totally new to caching so I may be missing some details or clarity, so please help me reformulate my question if needed

Comment: So you're saying you have cached data that has expiring links within it?  Sounds like you'd have to expire the cache when the links expire (which would be a tricky thing to do) so the cache would be refreshed with the new links

Comment: Indeed. Seems to be no other way.

Comment: How about using a url in your own domain that generates the s3 url and then redirects there?

Comment: Yes. I am working on this actually. But since those temporary links are used to display images thumbs, I would need the users to click on the link to display the image right? Unless I call this Url through javascript?